# Is it correct to print long HTML via PHP?

Tags: php, html, oop

I would like to know if it is correct to print long html through php classes with echo instead of just print it in a normal way, for example do the following:

Supose i have an user class

```
User.php

class User {

   private $name, $age;

   public function __construct($name, $age) {

      $this->name = $name;
      $this->age = $age;

   }

   public function printProfile($name, $age) {

     echo '<div class="panel panel-profile">

            Name: '.$this->name.'<br />
            Age: '.$this->age.'<br />
         </div>';
  }
}
```

And my profile.php would look something like

```
profile.php

<html lang="en">

<head>

        <?php 

            require_once __DIR__ . "/Head.php 
            $head = new Head();
            $head->printPanel();

        ?>

</head>

<body>
       <?php 

           require_once __DIR__ . "/Header.php 
           $header = new Header();
           $header->printPanel();

       ?>
<div class="content">

       <?php 

          require_once __DIR__ . "/User.php 
          $user = new User();
          $user->printProfile();

       ?>
</div>
       <?php 

         require_once __DIR__ . "/Footer.php 
         $footer = new Footer();
         $footer->printPanel();

       ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So.. I know it's possible but i don't know if is it correct to do that, am i making a proper use of the code? will influence the processing speed?
I like this way because i can reduce the code in all the pages, and just by changing the class it modify all the code. I also know that i could make something like

```
<?php require_once __DIR__ . "/header.php ?>
```

And include all the code there without making a class

```
header.php

<header>

  some stuffs

</header>
```

But i don't really like this because it is not object-oriented.

Sorry about my english as you may have noticed i'm not really good at it.

Comment: It's just coding style. The order that you put things won't make any difference to performance.

Comment: I think most programmers would consider it better to put all the `require` statements and variable assignments at the beginning, and just call the functions in the HTML blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, object orientation isn't everything. If you can do just as much procedurally, do it. In your case, for a simple website, you can get away with storing all of your chunks in a separate file, say, `Chunks.php`. Use one function for each of the pieces you want to add. You don't need 20 different classes with constructors for each element on the page. Just use static methods.

As for code style, put all your requires at the top so your page doesn't crash half way through rendering:

```
<?php require_once __DIR__ . "/Chunks.php ?>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <?php Chunks::printHead(); ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php Chunks::printHeader(); ?>
        <div class="content">
           <?php Chunks::printUserProfile(); ?>
        </div>
       <?php Chunks::printFooter(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Simple, easy to read, and does exactly what you expect without 30 different 20-line files clogging up your view.

Answer (score 1):

Using echo to output the html to the screen is more typical today.

> PHP echo and print Statements echo and print are more or less the
>   same. They are both used to output data to the screen.
>
> The differences are small: echo has no return value while print has a
>   return value of 1 so it can be used in expressions. echo can take
>   multiple parameters (although such usage is rare) while print can take
>   one argument. echo is marginally faster than print.

You can read more about that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_echo_print.asp)

You should add the require imports to the top of the page. which is what most people do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Your answers have been very useful, i'll begin using more statics methods.
I've been doing some simples websites, with javascript, jquery, html and php but i'm about to start a larger project and i wanted to clarify some stuffs.
You said **In your case, for a simple website, ...** but what about a larger website? the same applies?

Comment: Depends what you mean by larger. In your case you're just loading pieces from a different file to keep your view clean. Usually you would need object-specific methods to justify an object oriented approach.